# Bluetooth Device Data

Tags: fcc

I know the FCC makes data available in order to to enable sites like this one about [FCC ID look ups](https://fccid.report/), but I can't seem to find data about Bluetooth devices via api, as you woul find [here](https://device.report/usm-u-schaerer-sons/lock1c). Does anyone know where FCC device information is shared? Is that via API?